# How can I turn off window titlebars (window decorations) in gnome shell/mutter?

Tags: gnome, window-management, window-decoration

There's a shell extension called Maximus that disables window decorations when windows are maximized, but I'd like to disable window decorations entirely, for all windows (just using keyboard shortcuts to work with them). Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I'd use killall mutter or killall metacity.

Comment: "No process found" for both. But aren't those programs also window managers?

Comment: AFAIK Mutter is the compositor in Gnome Shell and Metacity handles the window decorations.

Comment: @Jon what about `killall gtk-window-decorator`?

Comment: @Salem, `gtk-window-decorator: no process found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do it myself, following [the instructions under "Method 2" here,](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html) but making those changes for the block beginning `frame_geometry name="normal"` instead of `max`. Now I don't have any borders. Great for using the extension Shellshape as a tiling window manager.

Answer (score 0):

In almost 2022, Unite extension can remove titlebar on all windows, maximized or minimized, x11 or wayland ! A must have.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/